# Mitigating User-Facing Effects of Mailbomb Attack

Tags: email, security

If thisn't the right group, let me know.

I am the lucky one who just was targeted in a mailbomb attack. So, I am getting thousands of emails (literally) and wondered whether anyone has developed a strategy for reducing the user (me) impact of this attack.

I'm using a server that has Sieve rules-based filtering if anyone thinks that might help me. I'm getting emails from all over the world, so I can't do anything language-specific to filter.

Thanks

Comment: Radically change your mail user password to something strong and not understood. Do that right away and the mail bombing should stop. Then cleanup afterward.

Comment: There is no single answer to this.  It really depends on the nature of the attack - its a matter of looking for cominalities in emails and blocking those. Greylisting might or might not help.

Comment: Ok… it seems that four languages with Roman characters, the commonality is that they say, “Thank you xThdzsfg”. A jumble of consonants. Any experience using Sieve script to filter Mail bodies for this kind of thing? A regex?

Comment: @John How will changing the password help?

Comment: It was just a suggestion to see if that would help.

Answer (score 1):

If the attack is still going you could forward your email to a Gmail account. Gmail has excellent spam filtering built in. Or you could try to find something that all mailbomb-mails have in common and create a spam filter rule to block them.

If the attack is finished, you may be able to download all your mail from the server, delete the mailbomb-mails (e.g. you can use grep to create a list of them if they have a phrase in common), and reupload them.